# Настройка Shеduler'a в Win XP SP3

Tags: администрирование, windows-xp

Вопрос по Sheduler'у в ОС Windows XP SP3
Я пытаюсь настроить задание по дням, но окно (фото вставить репутация не позволяет), но окно показывает лишь букву "к" справа с самого края и всё.
И так на всех ПК с аналогичной ОСХотелось бы узнать, это глюк системы или у меня какой-то дистрибутив кривой (хотя качался с microsoft.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

настрой на компе где работает, и просто скопируй job на флешку, скорее всего баг дистрибутива

Comment: @MalusСпасибо, как бы так и пришлось делать.Видать какая-то винда кривая, хотя Лицензия!